# Отследить отпускание клавиши python

Tags: python, winapi, клавиатура

Вопрос простой. Я пишу свою функцию отлова события с клавишами. Решил написать функцию, которая срабатывает ОДИН РАЗ после нажатия и отпускания. Т.е. она возвращает False, пока клавиша отпущена, пока она нажата. Но вернет True, как только клавишу отпустили после нажатия. Но лишь 1 раз. Потом снова False.

Сделал набросок функции:

```
import win32api as wapi
from random import randint as rd

RC_KEY_STATE = False

def isKeyPressed(key):

        state = wapi.GetKeyState(key)
        if state == -127 or state == -128:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def wasKeyPressed(key):
        
        if isKeyPressed(key):

            RC_KEY_STATE = True
            return False

        else:

            if RC_KEY_STATE:
                    
                RC_KEY_STATE = False
                return True
                
            return False
while True:
    print(wasKeyPressed(0x01))
```

Я запускаю эту функцию в бесконечном цикле. В принципе, эта функция очень даже работает. Но лишь для одной кнопки. Если я попытаюсь так прослушивать несколько кнопок, то работа будет некорректной по вполне понятным причинам - переключатель RC_KEY_STATE один.

Вопрос: как мне отследить ОТПУСКАНИЕ клавиши после нажатия? Не так, чтобы функция выполнялась все время, пока клавиша нажата/отжата, а только в момент отпускания. Правильный ли путь я выбрал или все гораздо сложнее? Есть ли какой-либо модуль, позволяющий это сделать? Может в win api есть такое? (не нашел)

Заранее спасибо

Comment: сделайте список, вернее словарь

Comment: Список/словарь чего? Переключателей для каждой кнопки? 200 iq ход. А если кнопок на проверку много?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Относительное решение все таки нашел. Изначально моя ошибка была в том, что я делил ситуацию на черное и белое. Ошибка изначально была в мышлении, что кнопка может быть либо нажата, либо отжата (False/True), а другого не дано. Нужно было использовать не False/True, а ID кнопок для сравнения, что дает куда больше возможностей.

Код:

```
import win32api as wapi
from random import randint as rd

RC_LAST_KEY = -1

def isKeyPressed(key):

    state = wapi.GetKeyState(key)
    if state == -127 or state == -128:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def wasKeyReleased(key):

    global RC_LAST_KEY
        
    if isKeyPressed(key) and RC_LAST_KEY == -1:

        RC_LAST_KEY = key

    elif not isKeyPressed(key) and RC_LAST_KEY == key:

        RC_LAST_KEY = -1
        return True

    return False
```

Не обращайте внимания на global - эти функции у меня в модуле. По-другому доступ к переменной уровня модуля получить нельзя - причуда Python, о которой я узнал не так давно, когда мой скрипт умирал по неадекватным причинам.

У данного способа есть свои недостатки, вроде не совсем корректной работы, когда нажимаются и отжимаются две проверяемые клавиши поочередно, но, в целом, результат меня устраивает.

Если есть более корректные способы и более удобные - я с радостью посмотрел бы.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте через keybord:

```py
import keyboard


def press_key(key):
    k = key.event_type
    if k == "down":
        print("ВНИЗ!", key.name)
    if k == "up":
        print("ВВЕРХ!", key.name)


keyboard.hook(press_key)
keyboard.wait()
```

Вариант 2 с потоками:

```py
from threading import Thread
import time
import keyboard


def press_key(key):
    k = key.event_type
    if k == "down":
        print("ВНИЗ!", key.name)
    if k == "up":
        print("ВВЕРХ!", key.name)


def run_key():
    keyboard.hook(press_key)
    keyboard.wait("Esc")


def fun1():
    # Код паралельно потоку thread1
    for i in range(5):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)


thread1 = Thread(target=run_key)
thread2 = Thread(target=fun1)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()

print("Код после потока")
```

Comment: Данный способ не подходит, если я правильно помню документацию по keyboard. Потому что моя функция должна быть в бесконечном цикле. Здесь же идет перехват и .wait() заставляет основной код ждать нажатой клавиши. Если я не прав, то поправьте меня. Я был бы рад увидеть данный способ в реализации с бесконечным циклом. Свой способ я также нашел и прикрепил его ниже, но у него есть недочеты.

Comment: @CSharpLooser только если вариант с потоками. Не уверен правда подойдет ли в Вашем случае. Дополнил ответ может кому надо будет.